# Joomla plugins are not working even when they are enabled

Tags: plugin

I installed some Joomla plugins but they are not working at all. I checked the plugin states and found that they were enabled.

I even added some code to the plugins to check whether they were getting called or not and found that the plugins were not getting called.

Could someone provide me with some help here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually occurs when plugins are not loaded in the system.
You can disable joomla caching and clean the cache.

Joomla caching setting is available in Global configuration.